# Select2.js error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, jquery-select2

I am using Select2 jquery plugin and I can't get results with json. When looking json response in browser it looks ok. Like this for example:

```
[{
        "id" : "50",
        "family" : "Portulacaceae "
    }, {
        "id" : "76",
        "family" : "Styracaceae "
    }, {
        "id" : "137",
        "family" : "Dipsacaceae"
    }
]
```

URL called with ajax in this case is: `http://localhost/webpage/json_family.php?term=acac&_=1417999511783` but I can't get that results in select2 input, console says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Here is code:

**html**

```
<input type="hidden" id="select2_family" name="term" style="width:30%" />
```

**js**

```
$("#select2_family").select2({
  minimumInputLength: 3,
  ajax: {
   url: "json_family.php",
   dataType: 'json',
   data: function (term) {
       return {
         term: term,
       };
   },
   results: function (data) {
     return { results: data.results };
   }

  }
});
```

**php**

```
$myArray = array();
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id,family FROM family WHERE family LIKE '%$term%'")) {
    $tempArray = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
            $tempArray = $row;
            array_push($myArray, $tempArray);
        }
    echo json_encode($myArray);
}
```

Is there error in code?

Comment: try my updated php. not familiar enough with the plugin to whip right to the issue, but I've skimmed some of the docs. hopefully you'll get this working soon

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, i have your example working on my test server, please do the following

change your query to this, changed a few names for readability but should be the same functionality, important part is addition of "AS TEXT" in query

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, family AS text FROM family WHERE family LIKE '%$term%'"));
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
           $return[] = $row;
         }

    echo json_encode($return);
```

second, it looks like you are trying to call a property from the json response called "results"

if that was the case your json should look like this, note that family is now text due to the change above:

```
{
"results":
[
    {
        "id": "50",
        "text": "Portulacaceae "
    },
    {
        "id": "76",
        "text": "Styracaceae "
    },
    {
        "id": "137",
        "text": "Dipsacaceae"
    }
]
}
```

But your php does not create the property results, so change your results function to remove the .results property call

```
   results: function (data) {
     return { results: data };
   }
```

final code i used (note i did not escape/sanitize the $_GET[term] or bind it to the query, recommend you do so ) if you are still having issues i can send you a link to my site example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#select2_family").select2({
  minimumInputLength: 3,
  ajax: {
   url: "select2.php",
   dataType: 'json',
   data: function (term) {
       return {
         term: term,
       };
   },
   results: function (data) {
     return { results: data };
   }
  }
});

});
</script>

<input type="hidden" id="select2_family" name="term" style="width:30%" />

</html>
```

**php**

```
<?

/*** connection strings ***/

// get the database singleton instance
$yog = MySqlDatabase::getInstance();

// connect
try {
    $yog->connect($host, $user, $password, $db_name);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}

$term = $_GET['term'];

if (!$term){
$sub = $yog->query("SELECT id, family AS text FROM family");
} else {
$sub = $yog->query("SELECT id, family AS text FROM family where family like '%$term%'");
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sub)) {
       $return[] = $row;
     }

echo json_encode($return);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note: just a stab at it. Just what stuck out.**

Your json has no property results, so try.

```
$("#select2_family").select2({
  minimumInputLength: 3,
  ajax: {
   url: "json_family.php",
   dataType: 'json',
   data: function (term) {
       return {
         term: term,
       };
   },
   results: function (data) {

     // CHANGED
     return { results: data };

   }

  }
});
```

**changed the query -- see if this helps**

```
$myArray = array();

// here
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, family AS text FROM family WHERE family LIKE '%$term%'")) {
    $tempArray = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
            $tempArray = $row;
            array_push($myArray, $tempArray);
        }
    echo json_encode($myArray);
}
```

Comment: I get same error as I commented in above answer. Old one doesn't show up anymore but this 'toUpperCase' is shown and no data again

Answer (score 1):

you need to define the `text` property on the results

and you might need to add `formatResult` and `formatSelection`

```
$("#select2_family").select2({
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    ajax: {
        url: "json_family.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function (term) {
            return {
                term: term,
            };
        },
        results: function (data) {return { results: data, text: 'family'}; },
        formatResult: function(item) { return item.family; }, 
        formatSelection: function(item) { return item.family; }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I do that new error is shown: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined