# getting error when trying to use ajax with select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Any idea how to debug the ajax funtionality of select2? Here's an example of what I'm trying to implement: https://jsbin.com/sohupoviko/edit?html,output and 
here's the result set for http://localhost:4000/users:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Smith"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "John2",
    "last_name": "Smith2"
  }
]
```

This is the local error being returned when I run the code locally:

```
jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at d (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js:2:5214)
    at Object.f.transport.d.status.0.d.status.e.trigger.message (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js:2:4227)
    at j (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js:2:29948)
    at k (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js:2:30262) undefined
```

Any idea what the root cause might be or how to debug?

Answer (score 0):

In your BackEnd code please change your query to use *"AS TEXT"*

Example:

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, first_name, last_name AS text FROM users WHERE fist_name LIKE '%$term%'"));
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
       $return[] = $row;
     }

echo json_encode($return);
```

Credit goes to -> [Select2.js error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27349882/select2-js-error-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined)

Comment: my backend is different.  it's a simple db.json file with a few hard-coded json objects.  json-server returns the file info as json.  I made sure that all property names and values were included in quotes *but this didn't fix the issue*.  is there some type of additional routine I can perform on the result object like JSON.stringify() or break apart the select2 processing functions to workaround this error?  s