# How to use Jquery Select2 with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use select 2 with ajax.

I see that ajax documentation is poor in select2
What am I missing here?
I am getting the next error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at d (select2.min.js:2)
    at Object.f.transport.d.status.0.d.status.e.trigger.message (select2.min.js:2)
    at Object.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at y (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery.min.js:4)
```

My json is:

```
[{"codigo":12,"nome":"Acre"},{"codigo":27,"nome":"Alagoas"},{"codigo":13,"nome":"Amazonas"},{"codigo":16,"nome":"Amapá"}]
```

My JS is:

```
$(".estado-ajax").select2({
            minimumInputLength: 2,
            tags: [],
            ajax: {
                url: '/getestados/',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: "GET",
                quietMillis: 50,
                data: function (term) {
                    return {
                        term: term
                    };
                },
                formatResult: function (data, term) {
                    return data.nome;
                },
                results: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    return {
                        results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { 
                                text: item.nome,
                                id: item.codigo
                            }
                        })
                    };
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Did you check you have at least one select with the class "estado-ajax"?

Comment: Hi, My  ajax is working because I can see the values into 'network' from chrome dev tools. The error occur after I type into select box. And yes, I did check and I have the select. In chrome dev tools, I can see the ajax return as posted above.

Comment: did you check this link?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27349882/select2-js-error-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined

Comment: I just checked. I get rid off the error but the dropdown list is not fiiled while I type. I´d like to see all items matched while I type a search. And, when I type backspace the select box stucks in two chars and I can´t delete them.